# I want to upgrade my app from sencha touch 2.1.1 to 2.2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, upgrade, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-touch-2.2

I use sencha touch 2.1.1 for my app. But now I want to upgrade my app to sencha touch 2.2.1
I go through http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/upgrade_1_to_2 link but they did not get steps for how I can upgrade.
So please any one know the proper steps for upgrading my app from sencha touch 2.1.1 to 2.2.1 the please help me.

Comment: As 2.1.1 to 2.2.1 is not a major version change I would not expect any changes in the API and therefore no needed changes in your code. Just replace the old version with the new one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the cmd to upgrade your app to a new sdk:

```
cd /path/to/www/myapp
sencha app upgrade /path/to/new_version_of_sdk
```

Comment: Thanks, I do that and It is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

in order to update your app make sure to follow this checklist:

- Download the new version.
- unpack it and replace the sencha touch lib in you app with newer version
- run the app and make sure nothing get messed up due to new version changes
- precede the correction if there is any.